# How to validate options for Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation

I am working on a Visual Studio extension and I want to add a single configuration option to Visual Studio where a user can specify a path to a particular directory.

Microsoft has several [tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166195.aspx) that describe how to add an options page using the `DialogPage` class, but I could not find how validate options provided by a user. In my case I want to check if a provided path is valid directory path.

I've add a `DialogPage` like this:

```
[Guid("92D0E244-D0DA-458C-88FB-9C0827000000")]
public class OptionPageGrid : DialogPage
{
    private string path = "C:\\Data";

    [Category("MyPlugin")]
    [DisplayName("Path data")]
    [Description("Path to data")]
     public string DataPath
    {
        get { return path; }
        set { path = value; }
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to validate that string `path` is a valid path. I tried to find a way to add an event handler to process on-save or on-apply event, but I could not find anything relevant.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override OnApply:

```
protected override void OnApply(PageApplyEventArgs e)
```

https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/GUI/SqlCe35Toolbox/Options/OptionsPageGeneral.cs#L102